# Problema ao enviar arquivos para bitBucket

Tags: git, repository, bitbucket

Estou entando enviar os arquivos commitados para base de dados, porem não está funcionando, estou fazendo tudo correto porem está dando a seguinte mensagem.

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false push -v --tags 

origin master:master
fatal: unable to access 'MEU SITE': SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

Pushing to MEUSITE.GIT

Completado com erros, veja acima.
```

O que pode ter causado o erro ? E como resolver ?

Comment: Você está se conectando via HTTPS ou SSH? Nunca usei o BitBucket com git (só com mercurial), mas lembro que o processo de conectar com SSH era mais complicado do que com HTTPS, envolvendo certificados no lado cliente. Com HTTPS tudo o que eu precisei fazer foi entrar com minha senha.

Comment: Nao, sei como posso olhar isto, para enviar utilizo o SourceTree

Comment: este site que utilizo para conectar. https://meulogin@bitbucket.org/meulogin/painel-administrativo-mc.git/

Comment: Eu não conheço o SourceTree, teria que olhar a documentação deles. A propósito, uma [busca rápida no Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=SSL+certificate+problem%3A+unable+to+get+local+issuer+certificate) me mostrou que esse erro normalmente é relativo a um problema com o certificado *do servidor*, então esquece o que falei sobre certificados no cliente... Sugiro procurar nas opções do SourceTree um meio de evitar a verificação SSL para seu repositório específico ("perigoso", mas seria uma solução a curto prazo).

Comment: P.S. Achei [isso](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/260358/clone-failes-with-unable-to-access-url-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate) no próprio site da Atlassian, veja se ajuda...

Comment: É o link nao me foi tao util, será que é porque eu estou com site no www do wamp ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seguindo oque o `mgibsonbr` indicou, uma maneira rápida e simples de desligar a verificação de Certificado SSL seria por esse comando `git config --global http.sslVerify false`, espero que lhe ajude.

Comment: Obrigado deu certinho.

Comment: Agora qual os riscos deste comando ? O que acontece ?

Comment: Desabilitar a verificação pode tornar seu código vulnerável a ataques MIM(Man-in-the-Midle), é uma forma de ataque em que os dados trocados entre duas partes, por exemplo você e o seu banco, são interceptados e possivelmente alterados pelo invasor sem que as vitimas percebam.

Comment: Eu utilizo o Bitbucket e o SourceTree como você, [aqui](http://www.gpickin.com/index.cfm/blog/git-for-dummies-creating-your-ssh-keys-for-bit-bucket) tem um tutorial de como você poderia gerar uma chave SSH, tanto via console quanto pelo próprio SourceTree, e se quizer saber mais informações sobre [SSH Keys](http://www.princiweb.com.br/blog/programacao/controle-de-versao/como-usar-ssh-key-no-git.html).